# How to integrate $\int x^2 \sin^2(x)dx$

Tags: integration

I don't know how to integrate $\int x^2\sin^2(x)\,\mathrm dx$. I know that I should do it by parts, where I have 
$$
u=x^2\quad  v'=\sin^2x \\ 
u'=2x \quad v={-\sin x\cos x+x\over 2}$$
 and now I have

$$
\int x^2\sin^2(x)\,\mathrm dx = {-\sin x\cos x+x\over 2} x^2 - \int 2x{-\sin x\cos x+x\over 2}\,\mathrm dx\\
={-\sin x\cos x+x\over 2} x^2 - \int x(-\sin x\cos x+x)\,\mathrm dx\\ 
$$ 
so I have to calculate
$$
\int x(-\sin x\cos x+x)\,\mathrm dx=-\int x\sin x\cos x\,\mathrm dx+\int x^2\,\mathrm dx$$

I know that $\int x^2\,\mathrm dx = {1 \over 3}x^3+C$ but I don't know what should I do with $$\int x\sin x\cos x \,\mathrm dx$$ Should i use parts again or what? Please help.

Comment: Yep, you should integrate by parts again.  You might be interested in the trig identity $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$.

Answer (score 5):

We have $\sin x \cos x=\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x$. Now another integration by parts will do it.

It may be marginally easier to note at the beginning that $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2 x$. So we want to integrate $\dfrac{1}{2}x^2(1-\cos 2x)$, that is, $\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{2}\cos 2x$, which looks more familiar.

Comment: Well of course! Thank you for your help, greetings from Poland :)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is in @Andre's answer but, I'd like to note you a simple  way for solving the latter integral:

[image]

Comment: Nice table! Great visual...+1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy. I made it wit office Word